# Get rows where contact has 20 activities within a minute - SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-delete, window-functions

We are collecting some analytics data for contacts & each page they visit. A lot of the analytics data is from malicious attacks or bots, so they are hitting like 20+ pages of the site in under a minute. I want to be able to purge this data once a day but cant figure out how to write a SQL query that will select all rows where that contact visited more than 20 pages in a minute, not just the past minute, but throughout the day. How would I write the query to get the rows of the activities by contacts that had groups of 20 + activities within a minute of each other?

The analytics table has DateCreated, ContactID, ActivityName, ActivityUrl

Sample Data (lets pretend its more than 3 within a minute):

```
2020-07-25 23:59:58, 78, Page visit, /home  
2020-07-25 23:59:57, 78, Page visit, /home/1  
2020-07-25 23:59:58, 34, Page visit, /home/2  
2020-07-25 23:59:56, 78, Page visit, /home/3  
2020-07-25 23:59:55, 78, Page visit, /home/4  
2020-07-25 23:59:52, 34, Page visit, /home  
2020-07-25 23:59:52, 78, Page visit, /home/5   
2020-07-25 23:59:51, 34, Page visit, /home/5   
2020-07-25 23:59:50, 34, Page visit, /home/6        
2020-07-25 21:34:02, 764, Page visit, /home   
2020-07-25 22:11:01, 78, Page visit, /home/9
```

Desired data:

```
2020-07-25 23:59:58, 78, Page visit, /home  
2020-07-25 23:59:57, 78, Page visit, /home/1  
2020-07-25 23:59:56, 78, Page visit, /home/3  
2020-07-25 23:59:55, 78, Page visit, /home/4   
2020-07-25 23:59:52, 78, Page visit, /home/5   
2020-07-25 23:59:58, 34, Page visit, /home/2  
2020-07-25 23:59:52, 34, Page visit, /home    
2020-07-25 23:59:51, 34, Page visit, /home/5  
2020-07-25 23:59:50, 34, Page visit, /home/6
```

Comment: @user6383418 . . . You basically asked the same question already, and haven't addressed the answers there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with two levels of window functions. The first level computes the number of requests per `contactID` and minute, then the second level takes that maximum count of the first computation per `contactID` and day. The final step is filtering:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        max(cnt_minute) over(partition by ContactID, date(DateCreated)) max_cnt_minute
    from (
        select 
            t.*,
            count(*) over(partition by 
                ContactID,
                dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, DateCreated), 0)
            ) cnt_minute
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
where max_cnt_minute > 20
```

You can easily turn this to a `delete` statement (which seems to be your actual intent), using an updateable CTE:

```
with cte as (

    select 
        t.*,
        max(cnt_minute) over(partition by ContactID, date(DateCreated)) max_cnt_minute
    from (
        select 
            t.*,
            count(*) over(partition by 
                ContactID,
                dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, DateCreated), 0)
            ) cnt_minute
        from mytable t
    ) t
)
delete from cte where max_cnt_minute > 20
```